# Translate matching specific field Elasticsearch Query in RestClient Low Level Rest API client

Tags: json, elasticsearch

i want to translate this Elasticsearch Query into RestClient Low Level Client.

```
GET try1\_search   
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "process.pa_name":   "luca"
    }
  }
}
```

My JSON Data looks like ,

```
{
        "_index": "try1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "target": {
            "br_id": 0,
            "an_id": 0,
            "ai_id": 0,
            "explanation": [
              "element 1",
              "element 2"
            ]
          },
          "process": {
            "an_id": 1311,
            "pa_name": "micha"
          },
          "text": "hello world"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "try1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "target": {
            "br_id": 0,
            "an_id": 1,
            "ai_id": 1,
            "explanation": [
              "element 3",
              "element 4"
            ]
          },
          "process": {
            "an_id": 1311,
            "pa_name": "luca"
          },
          "text": "the all People are good"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wrote smothing like this , using the RestClient in Low Level Client, to Get all Entities from the JSON Data,

```
       try {
            RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")).build();

            Response response1 = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/try1/_doc/_search?size=" + 10, Collections.singletonMap("pretty", "true"));
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response1.getEntity());
            System.out.println("result is : " + responseBody);

        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("failure : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Can Anybody please help me to expand my code to get the above Elastic Search Query ?
I will be thankfull.

Comment: Which version of ElasticSearch Client are you using?

Comment: Version 6.3.1. thx